# Access and change a control in WPF from another window

Tags: c#, sql, .net, wpf

In **MainWindow.xaml** I have a TextBox with a name **tbName**. Underneath it I have a button with an OnClickEvent. I want to set the text of a a TextBlock named **welcomeRank1Tb** in another window called **EmployeeRank1** with the Text that has been entered in **tbName** Textbox. How do I access **welcomeRank1Tb** from MainWindow.xaml.cs and set the value of it to whatever is entered in **tbName**?

```
private void EmployeeRank1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // creat SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader instances
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        // try-catch block that looks for match between input and database information for EmployeeRank1
        try
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CompanyManagementSystemm.Properties.Settings.ZaimovDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            // create a query and select just the record we need 
            string query = "select * from EmployeeRank1 where Name = @name AND Password = @pass";

            // A local sqlconnection in a using statement ensure proper disposal at the end of this code 
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();

            // Let the database do the work to search for the password and name pair
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pbPassword.Password;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // If the reader has rows then the user/pass exists in the db table
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                EmployeeRank1 employeeRank1 = new EmployeeRank1();
                employeeRank1.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                NamePassNotMatchFrame.Content = new NamePassNotMatch();
            }
        }
        // catch a potential exception
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
        }
```

I want to change the value of welcomeRank1Tb in the `if (reader.HasRows)` statement

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but I would suggest using binding and having such an operation happen between respective viewmodels. Modifying a window from another window sounds like a code smell.

Comment: Set it right after you create the window?: `employeeRank1.welcomeRank1Tb.Text = tbName.Text`

Comment: @mm8 That actually worked. I don't know why I didn't even consider it as an option, even though it is logical. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it right after you create the window:

```
employeeRank1.welcomeRank1Tb.Text = tbName.Text;
```